# How to align 3 responsive images with captions in the same row?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with aligning three images with captions underneath it in a single row. I got to the point where it aligns in a row however when I shrink the page, the last image pops underneath and messes up the format of the webpage.

Any tips?

Here is my code:

```css
.contain {
    max-width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
}

.category {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px;
}

figcaption{
    font-size: .7em;
}

.d-img{
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<section class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <h1 class="header">
      Header
    </h1>
    <div class="inner-inner">


      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="" />
        <figcaption>Image 1</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="" />
        <figcaption>Image 2</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="" />
        <figcaption>Image 3</figcaption>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="p-container">
      <div class="inner-p">
        <br />
        <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id sapien justo. Pellentesque lacinia vel sem ac porta. Donec ullamcorper turpis metus, in maximus magna lobortis et. Curabitur eu metus vitae lacus faucibus auctor id vitae tortor. Integer id scelerisque leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc ultrices, massa eget elementum laoreet, nunc mauris bibendum est, in tristique sem orci sed metus. Ut elementum mi in massa imperdiet, sed tincidunt velit elementum. Fusce tempus odio id purus volutpat, ac tempor leo varius. Donec in quam ac ligula porta eleifend in a lacus. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `display: flex;` to your `inner-inner class`.

```css
.inner-inner {
  display: flex;
}

.contain {
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
}

.category {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
}

figcaption {
  font-size: .7em;
}

.d-img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<section class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <h1 class="header">
      Header
    </h1>
    <div class="inner-inner">


      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
        <figcaption>Image 1</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
        <figcaption>Image 2</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
        <figcaption>Image 3</figcaption>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="p-container">
      <div class="inner-p">
        <br />
        <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id sapien justo. Pellentesque lacinia vel sem ac porta. Donec ullamcorper turpis metus, in maximus magna lobortis et. Curabitur eu metus vitae lacus faucibus auctor id vitae tortor. Integer id scelerisque leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc ultrices, massa eget elementum laoreet, nunc mauris bibendum est, in tristique sem orci sed metus. Ut elementum mi in massa imperdiet, sed tincidunt velit elementum. Fusce tempus odio id purus volutpat, ac tempor leo varius. Donec in quam ac ligula porta eleifend in a lacus. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If you want to keep the paragraph in the same row, include it in the `inner-inner class`

```css
  .inner-inner {
  display: flex;
}

.contain {
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
}

.category {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
}

figcaption {
  font-size: .7em;
}

.d-img {
  width: 500px;
```

```html
<section class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <h1 class="header">
      Header
    </h1>
    <div class="inner-inner">


      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
        <figcaption>Image 1</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
        <figcaption>Image 2</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="category">
        <img class="d-img" src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
        <figcaption>Image 3</figcaption>
      </div>

      <div class="p-container">
        <div class="inner-p">
          <br />
          <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id sapien justo. Pellentesque lacinia vel sem ac porta. Donec ullamcorper turpis metus, in maximus magna lobortis et. Curabitur eu metus vitae lacus faucibus auctor id
          vitae tortor. Integer id scelerisque leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc ultrices, massa eget elementum laoreet, nunc mauris bibendum est, in tristique sem orci sed metus. Ut elementum mi in massa imperdiet, sed tincidunt velit elementum.
          Fusce tempus odio id purus volutpat, ac tempor leo varius. Donec in quam ac ligula porta eleifend in a lacus.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```